# How do I enable GDM login for root on Debian?

Tags: debian, pam, gdm

I want the root user to be able to log in via GDM on Debian Wheezy.

I have read about modifying GDM and/or PAM configuration files but the instructions I have found describe specific file layouts that don't seem to match the files I'm seeing. For example one recipe says to uncomment a line in the PAM configuration, and the line would have "root" in it, but there is no such line in the file.

Comment: Everybody's going to tell you not to do it.  If you give more background and reasons you might get some love. :-)

Comment: @RobertL, thank-you for the kind advice. I have read such remarks here and there. Since the recipes are out there for Fedora they might as well be out there for Debian, too. I have a ton of things that need doing on this VM and, while some of them could be done other ways, not all of them can, and some of the things that supposedly can be done other ways, I've attempted other ways already. For example, you can add users to groups using the command line, but when it doesn't work, where's the feedback? If I could operate the user management GUI under "Settings" as root, I'd have feedback.

Comment: Cardiff space man, that's the kind of information we like to see in the question.  I would ask about the specific problems you're having on the command line.   If there are problems on the command line, I don't recommend going several layers of abstraction up into a GUI to address it. The problem adding users to groups would make a good question imho.  What you're asking for seems like a band-aid (dirty band-aid at that), to cover up other problems you might be having, either with system configuration, or with your understanding of the system.  Best of luck with your endeavors!

Comment: Use `sudo`like every debian derivative expects.  If you need GUI access and root rights use `gksudo`

Comment: Just add `auth     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid eq 0 quiet` at the top of your `/etc/pam.d/gdm-password` and you should be good to go.